# Is there a JSON parser that tells where exactly the error is in a malformed json?

Tags: java, json, gson

I need to convert some strings programmatically generated into valid JSON.

I'm using Gson to validate a json string this way:

```
try{
    new com.google.gson.JsonParser().parse("{\"data\":\\\"some data...\"}");                
}catch(JsonParseException e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

I know this json is not ok, but I need to implement a way to know where exactly the error is.
If I validate that string in jsonlint, the error displayed is:

```
Parse error on line 2:
{    "data": \"somedata..."}
-------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

However, the exception message diplayed by Gson is not as descriptive:

```
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected value at line 1 column 9
```

So, is there a tool in java as descriptive as jsonlint for the validation messages?. I need to present it to a end user.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with using jsonlint then?

Comment: "Descriptive"? Do you need this to present to the user? Because the Gson message tells the same thing as Jsonlint, it is just not enumeration what a "value" technically is.

Comment: yes, I need to present the validation message to the user. I would use jsonlint but don't know how to integrate it to java. This will be  a swing application.

Comment: It is not the task of a parser to format error messages in an end user friendly way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try{
        JsonObject root = (JsonObject)new JsonParser().parse("{\"data\":\"some data...\"}");  
        System.out.println(root.toString());
    }catch(JsonParseException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: thanks but this time the string to be parsed is not malformed and the excepcion will not launch.